# Labeling a Bar Graph Created from a Grouped Pandas DataFrame where there's a NaN Category

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I create a nice and tidy grouped data frame and then I use that data in a simple seaborn barplot.   However, when I try to add labels to the bars, I get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

I know this is because there is only one value (instead of two) for one of the grouped categories.  How do I get it to label it "0"?

I've gone down the rabbit hole on this for a full day and haven't found anything.  Here are the things that I've tried (in many different ways):

- Inserting a row into the grouped dataframe.
- Using `pd.fillna()`.
- Creating a function to apply within the labeling clause.

I work with a lot of data that frequently encounters this sort of problem, so I would really appreciate some help in solving this.  It seems so simple.  What am I missing?  Thanks!

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

# my initial data set 
d = {'year' : [2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,],
     'status' : ["n","y","n","n","n"],
     'num' : [1,1,1,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# groupby to create another dataframe
df2 = (df["status"]
    .groupby(df["year"])
    .value_counts(normalize=True)
    .rename("Percent")
    .apply(lambda x: x*100)
    .reset_index())

# create my bar plot
f = plt.figure(figsize = (11,8.5))

ax1 = plt.subplot(2,2,1)
sns.barplot(x="year",
           y="Percent",
           hue="status",
           hue_order = ["n","y"],
           data=df2,
           ci = None)

# label the bars
for p in ax1.patches:
    ax1.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2., p.get_height(), '%d%%' % round(p.get_height()), 
        fontsize=10, color='red', ha='center', va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

Comment: And look if it's nan in last loop? `if not isnan(p.get_height()):` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with data where you have missing categories, a common trick that can be employed is stacking and unstacking the data.  The general idea can be viewed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47790528/adding-missing-values-in-pandas-by-categories).  Once the data is formatted, you are able to `fillna` with your fill value (in this case 0), and leave your code as is.

All you  have to do is replace your current creation of `df2` with the below code.

---

```
df2 = (df.groupby('year').status.value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)
          .unstack().stack(dropna=False).fillna(0)
          .rename('Percent').reset_index())
```

Which gives us:

```
   year status     Percent
0  2014      n   66.666667
1  2014      y   33.333333
2  2015      n  100.000000
3  2015      y    0.000000
```

Now, with no changes to your plotting code, I get this output:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You could handle the empty-bar case by setting the height to zero if `p.get_height()` returns NaN:

```
for p in ax1.patches:
    height = p.get_height()
    if np.isnan(height):
        height = 0
    ax1.text(p.get_x() + p.get_width()/2., height, '%d%%' % round(height), 
        fontsize=10, color='red', ha='center', va='bottom')
```

gives me

[image: example showing 0%]

Alternatively, you could expand your frame to ensure there's a zero there:

```
non_data_cols = df2.columns.drop("Percent")
full_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df[col].unique() for col in non_data_cols], names=non_data_cols)
df2 = df2.set_index(non_data_cols.tolist()).reindex(full_index).fillna(0).reset_index()
```

which expands to give me

```
In [74]: df2
Out[74]: 
   year status     Percent
0  2014      n   66.666667
1  2014      y   33.333333
2  2015      n  100.000000
3  2015      y    0.000000
```